# Error while updating confluence page

Tags: python, python-3.x, confluence

```
from pprint import pprint
from atlassian import Confluence

confluence = Confluence(
    url='xxx',
    username='xxx',
    password='xxx')

status = confluence.update_page(
    parent_id=22028117,
    page_id=38284221,
    title='',
    body='<h1 id="WindowsSignatureSet2.4.131.3-2-HandoffinstructionstoOperations">Handoff instructions to Operations</h1>',     
)

print(status)
```

Getting the error below while trying to update confluence page. Up until yesterday it was working fine. What went wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "con_update.py", line 37, in
parent_id=22028117
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\atlassian\confluence.py", line 76, in update_page
'version': {'number': version}})
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\atlassian_init_.py", line 57, in put
return self.request('PUT', path=path, data=data, headers=headers).json()
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\atlassian_init_.py", line 42, in request
response.raise_for_status()
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 851, in raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: can't use confluence api for update ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending incremented version number.for update process you have to increment version number by 1.

```
    from pprint import pprint
from atlassian import Confluence

confluence = Confluence(
    url='xxx',
    username='xxx',
    password='xxx')

status = confluence.update_page(
    parent_id=22028117,
    page_id=38284221,
    title='',
    version=x,//latest version number+1
    body='<h1 id="WindowsSignatureSet2.4.131.3-2-HandoffinstructionstoOperations">Handoff instructions to Operations</h1>',     
) print(status)
```